# CSS not loading through server

Tags: html, css

I am trying to run my web site off my own server using this: http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php.

While everything works great when I run my website locally and when I ran it on a real server, I cannot get the CSS to load while I run it through my own server.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html: charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>AddictingJava</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/default.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>

</header>
<!-- Navigation Start -->
<section class="Nav">       
        <section class="Logo">
            <nav class="HomeLogo">
                <a href="index.html" class="HomeLogoLink" title="Home"></a>
            </nav>  
        </section>
        <ul>
        <li><nav class="GamesButton">
            <a href="Games/games.html" class="GamesButtonLink" title="Games"></a></li>
        </nav>
        <li><nav class="ProfileButton">
            <a href="Profile/profile.html" class="ProfileButtonLink" title="Profile"></a></li>
        </nav>
        <li><nav class="ForumsButton">
            <a href="Forums/forums.html" class="ForumsButtonLink" title="Forums"></a>
                <ul id="DropNav">
                    <li><a href="Forums/GeneralDiscussion/generaldiscussion.html" title="General Discussion">General Discussion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Forums/Contact/contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>            
                </ul>
        </li>
        </nav>
        <li><nav class="NewsButton">
            <a href="News/news.html" class="NewsButtonLink" title="News"></a></li>
        </nav>
        </ul>
</section>
<nav class="Download">
    <a href="http://www.addictingjava.com/Jars/2014-06-21-WorldDomination AJ Client.jar">Get Client</a>
</nav>
        <!-- Navigation End -->
<section class="AboutSite">
    <article>
        <p>AddictingJava is a site dedicated to bringing you a unique experience with minI game sites. We hope to get user feedback as we grow and make the site a very fun place to visit overall. Although it doesn't seem like this site has very much we are currently planning a lot for it, so be sure to check back regularly to see when we update the site.<br><br>
        If you wish to download our client click <a href="Games/games.html">here</a> or the Get Client button above.
    </article>
</section>
<section class="RecentNews">
    <figure class="TopRecentNewsPicture">
        <img src="websitepics/newnewspic.png">
    </figure>
    <article class="TopRecentNews">
        <h5>7/7/2014 - Announcment.</h5>
        <p>Read all about things we are working on as of today.</p>
    </article>
    <figure class="MidRecentNewsPicture">
        <img src="websitepics/newgamepic.png">
    </figure>
    <article class="MidRecentNews">
        <h5>7/7/2014 - Client added.</h5>
        <p>The AddictingJava Client was added.</p>
    </article>
    <figure class="BotRecentNewsPicture">
        <img src="websitepics/newnewspic.png">
    </figure>
    <article class="BotRecentNews">
        <h5>3/14/2014 - Website created!!!!</h5>
        <p>The begining of everything.</p>
    </article>
</section>
<section class="footer">
    <p>© 2014 AddictingJava, Inc. All rights reserved. </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open up your browser's dev tools. Is the URL for the CSS accurate? What code is the get returning?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that your file path is correct to your css file.

This link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

assumes there is an uppercase `CSS` folder in the same folder as `javawebserver.php`.

if it is at the root it would be

```
/javawebserver.php 
/CSS/default.css
```

Comment: If it was in the wrong file path would that mean it would not work locally? cause it works locally also worked on  my paid server.

Comment: Not knowing your exact setup it's hard to tell. I would assume that locally you have a directory named CSS in the same directory as your php file. If this is the actual url you are talking about http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php it is looking for the css file here http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/CSS/default.css and when I click that link I get a 404 error,which mean no file exists on the server in that location. There could be a number of items with your local setup. Are you running a local web server? If so is you OS cases sensitive? Did you upload the css file to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your css-folder is renamed in uppercase. On a local machine (windows file systems) a reference to "css", "CSS" or even "cSs" is a reference to the same folder. So if your folder is named in lowercase the link would work on your local machine. 
Linux/UNIX file systems on the other hand are case sensitive so on an Apache web server the link would only work if the folder or file is referenced with the correct upper/lowercase.